Getting VSS Error ID 8200 while taking VSS Snapshot backup. API IVssWriterComponentsExt.GetWriterInfo is failed with error VSS_E_INVALID_XML_DOCUMENT
We are developing an application to backup our filesystem files via VSS. We are getting an issue while gathering writer component info which is blocking us to move ahead with building the tool. Can someone please help? Detailed logs here:
IVssBackupComponents::GetWriterComponentsCount() SUCCESS. WriterCompCount: 1 IVssBackupComponents::GetWriterComponents() SUCCESS. WriterIndex: 0 IVssWriterComponentsExt: 0x1becae04c50 IVssWriterComponentsExt::GetWriterInfo() FAILED. ERROR: VSS error: IVssWriterComponentsExt.GetWriterInfo: VSS_E_INVALID_XML_DOCUMENT - The given XML document is invalid. It is either incorrectly-formed XML or it does not match the schema. (0x5653535f455f494e56414c49445f584d4c5f444f43554d454e54202d2054686520676976656e20584d4c20646f63756d656e7420697320696e76616c69642e2049742069732065697468657220696e636f72726563746c792d666f726d656420584d4c206f7220697420646f6573206e6f74206d617463682074686520736368656d612e)
Event log:

Volume Shadow Copy Service error: An unexpected error was encountered examining the XML document. The document is missing the WRITER_COMPONENTS element.

Ran out of time while deleting files. 

Operation:
   OnPostSnapshot event
   PostSnapshot Event

Context:
   Execution Context: Shadow Copy Optimization Writer
   Execution Context: Writer
   Writer Class Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Writer Name: Shadow Copy Optimization Writer
   Writer Instance ID: {fd60e96c-2cb0-4e94-a096-1c57e98f690e}




VSS_E_INVALID_XML_DOCUMENT: The XML document is not valid.
According to the Event log: The XML document is missing the WRITER_COMPONENTS element.
I suggest you could refer to the Doc: Event and Error Handling Under VSS
And you could try to call CreateVssExamineWriterMetadata to examin the metadata obtained from a stored XML document by an instance of IVssExamineWriterMetadata obtained.

This has been resolved. The issue was with cpp virtual function pointers which were loaded in go after loading the vssapi.dll.

This has been resolved. The issue was with cpp virtual function pointers which were loaded in go after loading the vssapi.dll.
